# I am trying to hide sheets in excel when a cell contains a certain number

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have a excel workbook with a lot of sheets and I have some code where I hide the sheets if a certain range contains 0. It works the first time but when I try to use it again it stops working. Can you please help me?

This is the code I use when I hide them

```
Sub Shadow2()
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    j = Worksheets.Count
    For k = j To 3 Step -1
    If Range("AA2") = "0" Then
        Sheets(k).Visible = False
        End If
    Next k
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

And this is the one I use when I reveal them again.

```
Sub TaFramIgen()
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    j = Worksheets.Count
    For k = j To 1 Step -1
        Sheets(k).Visible = True
    Next k
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    j = 0
End Sub
```

When I have hidden them once and revealed them again I can not use Shadow2 code... nothing happens.

Can you please tell me what my problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Range("AA2")` is always checking the active sheet. Not the sheet you are trying to hide.

Comment: If you're wanting to check that value on the sheet in question just do `If Sheets(k).Range("AA2") = "0"`. Also note: `"0"` is different to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, this is my code

```
Sub Shadow2()
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim v As Variant




    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    j = Worksheets.Count
    For k = j To 3 Step -1
    Set cell = Sheets(k).Range("AA2")
    v = cell.Value
    Sheets(k).Activate
    If Application.IsNA(v) Then
        Sheets(k).Visible = False
    Else
        If cell = "0" Then
            Sheets(k).Visible = False
        End If
    End If
    Next k
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```